Routes OpenVPN on Ubuntu vs OpenVPN client on Windows behind router
I've installed OpenVPN server on remote Ubuntu on VPS (example of my static IP: 67.111.111.111) and configured it many times using different similar instructions where server.conf is most common:
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1

I use OpenVPN client for Windows to connect to remote server.
It connects with IPv4 10.8.0.2 and IPv6 fd42:... adresses! Some traffic due to statistics in application goes, but that's it! Nothing happens next.
No web surfing occurs and no pings to domains or IPs are available except ping to my server IP ping 67.111.111.111
My network is like that - MY_COMPUTER -> MY_ROUTRER (wifi) -> OpenVPN server@67.111.111.111
Please help from the top about all the routing settings needed on both - OpenVPN server, MY_COMPUTER and MY_ROUTER
PS: Routing is a total nightmare, beacuse I'm total noob at it.
